# difference between method and function

Tags: python

Some list operations are reached by a dot notation

```
C.append(e)
```

while other operations requires the list object as an
argument to a function, as in

```
len(C)
```

Why this happens?
Are there any rules whether functionality regarding an object is reached
through the first way (method) or the second one (function)?
Thanks.

Comment: Because you need a list to append, append is an instance method because you need an instance for it to work, but to find length you only need to pass an argument. `len` is a global builtin.

Comment: usually ones with brackets return a value

Comment: In the case of `len`, I believe it just calls the object's `__len__` method anyway. When in doubt, consult the documentation.

Comment: Related: [The advantages of having static function like len(), max(), and min() over inherited method calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1628222/190597).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference for many built-in functions. The global functions like `len`, `iter`, `str` are calls to object methods `__len__`, `__iter__`, `__str__` etc.

See [Basic customization](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) and [Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) in Python reference:

> object.`__len__`(self)
>
> Called to implement the built-in function len(). Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0. ...

Advantage of such soluttion is that an object can override these special functions just by overriding corresponding "double-underscore" methods, e.g `__len__`.

Although `append` does not have a built-in, since it is a less universal operation than `len`, `str` etc.